# list even numbers one through ten and each multiplied by 2

Tags: javascript

It might be a silly question; however, my code is not running. I was trying to **list even numbers one through ten and each multiplied by 2**. But I am not getting what I want. Please help me out what I missed in the code.

```js
var num; 
var list = ""; 
for(num = 0; num<=10; num++){ 
  num % 2 == 0;
  num *=2; 
  list += num + "<br>"; 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list; 
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Is there no change at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... Edit your post and add the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're modifying loop variable, you need to use different variable and you need to add if statement:

```js
var num, i;
var list = ""; 
for(i = 0; i<=10; i++){ 
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    num = i*2; 
    list += num + "<br>"; 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list; 
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Also `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` can be outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Like this should work just fine:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
  var num; 
  var list = ""; 
  for(num = 0; num<=10; num++){ 
  if(num % 2 == 0) list += (num * 2) + "<br>"; 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list; 
  } 
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your `num` variable inside the loop

Replace

```
num *=2; 
list += num + "<br>";
```

With

```
list += (num*2) + "<br>";
```

As an example if you would start with `num = 2`, you then multiply it by 2 `num *=2`. So, the next time you enter the loop, `num` will be 4. Which means you skipped 3!

Answer (score 0):

No need for modulo; just use a step in your loop:

```
for (var arr = [], i = 0, l = 10; i <= l; i+=2) {
  arr.push(i * 2);
}

arr.join('<br/>'); // 0<br/>4<br/>8<br/>12<br/>16<br/>20
```